# Dictionary to csv files using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

How do I convert multiple dictionaries into csv files using a for loop (and also have the dict names as the csv file name). Also how would I create a for loop to read the csv files into seperate dictionaries that are named according to the csv file name.

My problem is that the dictionaries take 12 hours or more to run in jupyter notebook and I am trying to find a way to not run them everytime my notebook shutdowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to provide code you have tried and small examples of your data.

This assumes the dictionaries are "flat" and can be easiy represented as csv files.
Note for dictionaries consider pickle instead for writing any python object

```
import pandas as pd

# dictionaries o f data
d1 = {'item11':1, 'item12': 2}
d2 = {'item21':3, 'item22': 4}

# dictionary of the data dictionaries with names
dicts = {'d1' : d1, 'd2' : d2}

# use pandas to make a dataframe and the write data frame to csv
for a_dict in dicts:
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicts[a_dict], orient="index", columns=['value']).to_csv("~/Downloads/"+a_dict+".csv", index_label="key")

# Reading into new names
new_d1 = pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/" + "d1" + ".csv", index_col=0).to_dict(orient='dict')['value']
new_d2 = pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/" + "d2" + ".csv", index_col=0).to_dict(orient='dict')['value']

assert d1 == new_d1
assert d2 == new_d2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried using pickle but Jupyter notebook does not support pickle. The dictionaries are all just one key and one value. Also, how would I read those csv files and convert them back to a dictionary with their respective names.

Comment: I tried to make the csv files but it raised an error 'If using all scalar values, you must pass an index'

Comment: Adjusted to better fit the dictionary structure described in your comment

Comment: Another concern was that I have hundreds of these dictionaries. Is there a for loop that can be made to read them?